# How to send msg along with rejectConnection in FMS

Tags: flash-media-server, fms3

in main.asc, i tried this but doesnot work :

```
   errObj = {} //new Object();
   errObj.msg = "You got a wrong username and password, disconnecting..." ; 
   application.rejectConnection(this.client,errObj)
```

What's the way out ?